# Is that sequence of probabilities non-decreasing?

Tags: probability

For some fixed integer $t>0$, let $S$ be a fixed non-empty set of $t$-bit bitstrings.

For integer $n\in[0,t]$, define $p_n$ to be the expectation of the following experiment:

- pick a bitstring uniformly at random in $S$
- truncate the bitstring to $n$ bits
- append $t-n$ uniformly random bits to make the bitstring $t$-bit again
- experiment succeeds if the bitstring is in $S$

Prove or disprove: $p_n$ is non-decreasing.

---

Obviously, $p_0$ is $\lvert S\rvert/2^t\le1$, and $p_t=1$, thus the proposition is true for $t=1$. Examination shows it's true for $t=2$.

Comment: Is ask the name of this theorem in an algorithmic framework, [there](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49135/19463).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an $n$-bit string $r$, let $s(r)$ denote the number of strings in $S$ whose $n$-bit truncation equals $r$. For example, if $n=0$ then $s($""$)=\#S$, while if $n=t$ then $s(r)=1$ if $r\in S$ and $s(r)=0$ if $r\notin S$. It's not hard to work out, by conditioning on the $t$-bit string initially chosen from $S$, that
$$
p_n = \frac{2^n}{2^t\#S} \sum_{n\text{-bit strings }r} s(r)^2.
$$
If $r_0$ and $r_1$ denote the result of appending $0$ and $1$, respectively, to $r$, then $s(r_0)+s(r_1)=s(r)$ and thus $s(r_0)^2+s(r_1)^2\ge \frac12s(r)^2$; this is enough to show that $p_{n+1}\ge p_n$ as claimed.